# How to disable selection freedrawing fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

After you draw something with FreeDrawing in FabricJs, you are able to select what was drawn and move it. Is there a way to disable this selection?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In case you don't need any interactivity on your canvas, you can use **StaticCanvas**

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('c');
```

Or, in case you want to disable selection only for specific objects, i.e. the last brush stroke, you can try calling the following code every time the stroke is created:

```
canvas.item(0).selectable = false;
canvas.renderAll();
```

---

If you need interactivity for other objects, you can also define this right after canvas initialization

```
fabric.Object.prototype.selectable = false;
```

all new objects will be non-selectable, unless you specify otherwise when you want to create a selectable object

```
var text = new fabric.Text('Honey,\nI\'m subtle', {
    fontSize: 250,
    left: 50,
    top: 0,
    selectable: true // make this object selectable
});
canvas.add(text);
```

Comment: How do I know when the stroke is created?  All I have set is this:                 canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

Comment: If you're always using the canvas in Drawing Mode, how do you have a problem with selection at all, you shouldn't be able to select any object until you exit the drawing mode

Comment: Im not using canvas in Drawing Mode always. I dont want to be able to select any object after I exit the drawing mode

Comment: Are you able to use the Static Canvas? Or you need interactivity for other objects on canvas?

Comment: i need interactivity for other objects on canvas

Comment: I updated the answer, this may be helpful give it a try

Comment: If I use fabric.Object.prototype.selectable = false; the per pixel drag and drop does not work. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

In case of needing interactivity in some objects but not in all of them, you can set: `evented: false` in the creation of non interactive objects.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Rect.html#evented

Comment: This should be indeed accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The selectable corners / borders and/or controls can be disabled as well. Here is the full code:

```
    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');    
    fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
    canvas.selection = false;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function (img) {

        height = img.getBoundingRectHeight();
        width = img.getBoundingRectWidth();

        var oImg;
        oImg = img
            .set({ hasControls: false, hasBorders: false, selectable: false })
            .scale(factor);
        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
        canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
    }, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' });
```