# How to prevent clicking on any other object or canvas

Tags: fabricjs

I have an need to prevent the user to be unable to click on any other object (or the canvas itself) beyond the currently selected object.

In other words, once the user selects an object, and clicks a particular button, I want all other clicks to be ignored except those for the selected object. So the user can still interact with the selected object (scale, transform, etc.). The user would need to click another button to leave this "mode".

I've tried handling this by just returning in the mouse:down event handler as well as trying stopPropagation() for the event.

I can prevent clicking on other objects by setting evented=false, etc, but I can't seem to "ignore" clicking on a blank portion of the canvas.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038404/how-to-disable-selection-freedrawing-fabricjs  there are a couple  of  ideas .

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't think that quite solves for my current situation, but I appreciate the help.